# How to Convert Special Characters in Java

Tags: java, string, split, special-characters

I have these set of strings that I get from a `PostgreSQL` DB:

```
"WITH DELIMITER E'\037'"
"WITH DELIMIER E'\01f'"
"WITH DELIMITER '|'"
```

I need to extract whatever is between the single quotes and use it to split and join a string. Something along the lines:

```
String delimiter = delimiter.substring(delimiter.indexOf("'")+1, delimiter.indexOf("'",delimiter.indexOf("'")+1));
String[] splitString = originalString.split(delimiter);
//Do something with it...
String joinedString = StringUtils.join(splitString, delimiter);
```

The problem is that Java takes \037 (read from DB into a String) and reads it as \\037 (would print as "\037") and I need \037 (the special character) for the split and join functions.

I need a way to take the values between single quotes (\037, \01f, |, and so on) and convert them to special characters.

That would be:

```
String originalString = "\\037"
String convertedString = "\037"
```

Also, the pipe (|) is a metacharacter in **`Java`** and in order for me to split it I had to do the following:

```
String[] splitString = originalString.split(Pattern.quote("|"));
```

I don't want to do an if condition, I would like something better.
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Wow, you are right! I used the second solution as it was easier to understand. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [this](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat.html). It's more easy and you don't care about the special character.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Wouldn't I be having the same issue? If I call it with function withDelimiter(char delimiter) I would still be having to send the special character, right?

Comment: Hi Rom! Your answer looks useful, but it would be better if you provided a summary text in it, not just the link. That makes it quicker for readers to evaluate, and it continues being useful if the linked side disappears or moves. See *Provide context for links* in the [*How do I write a good answer?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) help page.